# Linking Assimp 3.1.1 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking, assimp

I am linking to assimp as i´ve always done with other middleware, but when i run my application, i get a runtime error: "Application could not launch correctly (0xc000007b)."

What am i missing? I downloaded the assimp 3.1.1 binary and got

- an include/assimp folder, containing header files and a "Compiler" folder containing more headers
- "lib32" and "lib64" folders, each containing an "assimp.lib"
- "bin32" and "bin64" folders, containing an "assimp.dll" and an "assimp.exe"
- ...along with other folders and files, like samples and cmake stuff.

I put the "include/assimp" folder into my projects include folder, the assimp.lib i put in my lib/x86 folder and the assimp.dll and .exe next to my application .exe.

In my startup-project´s properties i am linking to the include and library paths and i am including assimp.lib in my additional dependencies.

Comment: EDIT: The problem was that the assimp.dll and assimp.exe had to go into my solution folder. appearently somewhere this is defined as the place to read .dll or .exe from.. even though thats strange because my glew.dll and sdl2.dll need to be inside the same directory as my application.. Probably the assimp.exe assumes the .dll is in the directory above it

Comment: Just wanted to say that I had this problem today and without you posting your comment on how you fixed it, I would have been stuck forever. Thanks so so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the assimp.dll and assimp.exe had to go into my solution folder. appearently somewhere this is defined as the place to read .dll or .exe from.. even though thats strange because my glew.dll and sdl2.dll need to be inside the same directory as my application.. Probably the assimp.exe assumes the .dll is in the directory above it